# Laravel validation Failed to Upload

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-hook-form

I'm using Laravel on the backend and React.js on the frontend. When I use Laravel validation for images, the image fails to upload. However, if I don't use validation for images, it works correctly. I wonder why. Can you please help me?

Custom Hooks

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast.js";
import { formatISO } from "date-fns";
import { siswaDetail, siswaUpdate } from "@/features/siswaSlice.js";

function UseSiswaEdit() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { formError, formSuccess, formLoading, detailSiswa } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.siswa,
  );

  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      nama: "",
      nisn: "",
      agama: "",
      no_telpon: "",
      jenis_kelamin: "",
      tgl_lahir: "",
      tempat_lahir: "",
      foto: "",
      alamat: "",
    },
  });

  const storage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("siswaDetail"));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(siswaDetail(id));
    if (storage) {
      Object.keys(storage).forEach((key) => {
        form.setValue(key, storage[key]);
      });
    }

    if (formSuccess) {
      toast({
        title: "Success",
        description: "Data siswa berhasil diubah!",
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate("/siswa");
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [formSuccess, dispatch, form]);

  function onSubmit(values) {
    if (values.tgl_lahir) {
      values.tgl_lahir = formatISO(values.tgl_lahir, {
        representation: "date",
      });
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
      formData.append(key, values[key]);
    });
    dispatch(siswaUpdate({ id, formData }));
  }

  return {
    id,
    formLoading,
    formSuccess,
    formError,
    detailSiswa,
    onSubmit,
    form,
  };
}

export default UseSiswaEdit;
```

```
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card.jsx";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectGroup,
  SelectItem,
  SelectLabel,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select.jsx";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input.jsx";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover.jsx";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button.jsx";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils.js";
import { CalendarIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { Calendar } from "@/components/ui/calendar.jsx";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea.jsx";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
} from "@/components/ui/form.jsx";
import { asset } from "@/service/apiCall.js";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label.jsx";
import useSiswaEdit from "@/hooks/siswa/useSiswaEdit.jsx";

function SiswaEdit() {
  const { formLoading, formError, detailSiswa, onSubmit, form } =
    useSiswaEdit();
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>Ubah Data Siswa</CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>
          Mohon isi formulir ini dengan baik dan benar
        </CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="nama"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="name">
                      Nama
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        id="name"
                        placeholder="John Doe"
                        {...field}
                      />
                      {formError?.name ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.name[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="nisn"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="nisn">
                      NISN <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Input
                        type="number"
                        id="nisn"
                        placeholder="123xxx"
                        {...field}
                      />
                      {formError?.nisn ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.nisn[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="agama"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="agama">
                      Agama <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        id="agama"
                        placeholder="Islam"
                        {...field}
                      />
                      {formError?.agama ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.agama[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="no_telpon"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="no-telpon">
                      No. Telepon
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Input
                        type="number"
                        id="no-telpon"
                        placeholder="0823xxx"
                        {...field}
                      />
                      {formError?.no_telpon ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.no_telpon[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="jenis_kelamin"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="jenis-kelamin">
                      Jenis Kelamin
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Select
                        id="jenis-kelamin"
                        defaultValue={field.value}
                        onValueChange={field.onChange}
                      >
                        <SelectTrigger className="w-full">
                          <SelectValue placeholder="Pilih Jenis Kelamin" />
                        </SelectTrigger>
                        <SelectContent>
                          <SelectGroup>
                            <SelectLabel>Jenis Kelamin</SelectLabel>
                            <SelectItem value="laki-laki">Laki-Laki</SelectItem>
                            <SelectItem value="perempuan">Perempuan</SelectItem>
                          </SelectGroup>
                        </SelectContent>
                      </Select>
                      {formError?.jenis_kelamin ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.jenis_kelamin[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="tgl_lahir"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="tanggal-lahir">
                      Tanggal Lahir
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Popover>
                        <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                          <Button
                            variant={"outline"}
                            className={cn(
                              "w-[868px] justify-start text-left font-normal",
                              !field.value && "text-muted-foreground",
                            )}
                          >
                            <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                            {field.value ? (
                              format(field.value, "PPP")
                            ) : (
                              <span>Pick a date</span>
                            )}
                          </Button>
                        </PopoverTrigger>
                        <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0">
                          <Calendar
                            mode="single"
                            selected={field.value}
                            onSelect={field.onChange}
                            initialFocus
                          />
                        </PopoverContent>
                      </Popover>
                      {formError?.tgl_lahir ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.tgl_lahir[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="tempat_lahir"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="tempat-lahir">
                      Tempat Lahir
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        id="tempat-lahir"
                        placeholder="Pekanbaru, Indonesia"
                        {...field}
                      />
                      {formError?.tempat_lahir ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.tempat_lahir[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="alamat"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="alamat">
                      Alamat
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Textarea
                        type="text"
                        id="alamat"
                        placeholder="Jl. Sudirman No.xx"
                        {...field}
                      />
                      {formError?.alamat ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.alamat[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="foto"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
                  <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="foto">
                      Foto
                      <span className="text-red-500 font-bold">*</span>
                    </FormLabel>
                  </div>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                      <Input
                        id="foto"
                        type="file"
                        accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          field.onChange(
                            e.target.files ? e.target.files[0] : null,
                          )
                        }
                      />
                      {formError?.foto ? (
                        <p className="mt-2 ml-1 text-xs text-red-500">
                          {formError.foto[0]}
                        </p>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-12 gap-2 sm:gap-6 items-center mb-2">
              <div className="col-span-3">
                <Label htmlFor="name">Foto Sebelumnya</Label>
              </div>

              <div className="sm:col-span-9">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-5">
                  <img
                    src={asset(detailSiswa?.foto)}
                    alt=""
                    className="w-[230px] h-[200px] rounded-full"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mt-7 flex justify-end gap-x-2">
              <Link to="/siswa">
                <Button variant="outline">Kembali</Button>
              </Link>
              <Button type="submit" disabled={formLoading}>
                {formLoading ? "Loading" : "Submit"}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default SiswaEdit;
```

Validation

```
function update(): array
{
    return [
        'nama' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'nisn' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'jenis_kelamin' => 'required|in:laki-laki,perempuan',
        'agama' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'alamat' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'no_telpon' => 'required|string|max:13',
        'foto' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        'tempat_lahir' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'tgl_lahir' => 'required|date',
    ];
}
```

Controller Laravel

```
public function update(SiswaRequest $request, Siswa $siswa): JsonResponse
{
    $fotosiswa = null;

    if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($siswa->foto);
        $fotosiswa = $request->file('foto')->store('foto/siswa', 'public');
    }
    $siswa->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'nisn' => $request->nisn,
        'jenis_kelamin' => $request->jenis_kelamin,
        'agama' => $request->agama,
        'alamat' => $request->alamat,
        'no_telpon' => $request->no_telpon,
        'foto' => $fotosiswa ? $fotosiswa : $siswa->foto,
        'tempat_lahir' => $request->tempat_lahir,
        'tgl_lahir' => $request->tgl_lahir
    ]);

    if ($request->filled('roles')) {
        $siswa->syncRoles([$request->input('roles')]);
    }

    return response()->json($siswa);
}
```

The error after submit :
[Validation Message : Failed to Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWvN.png)

I tried to comment on validate image and it works properly

Comment: Please don't post [images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: @brombeer That's the wrong image. I apologize for the mistake. I have already edited the post."

Comment: Look at your console to see the details of error when you upload your image.

Comment: @VincentDecaux I already know what's happening. I tried to use the PATCH method for updating the data, but when I try using the POST method, it works fine. But I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Instead of posting all the code of your application, just explain clearly the problem. You can't send binary data through PATCH or PUT method, so your image is not sent in PATCH, only in POST.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for the new vocabulary.